# C scanning array diagonally

Tags: c, arrays

I have a project in C and I have to scan an `array[10][15]` diagonally as in the picture below.

[image]

I would like to help me to find how to scan the array this way...
Thank you very much.

P.S sorry for my english(I'm Greek)

Comment: Could not understand your image. Diagonally or around the sides along the left and then the bottom.

Comment: `scanf` has nothing to do with 'scanning arrays'.

Comment: Something like add or subtract 1 to the x and y offset of the 2d matrix array and if those values are in bounds, grab the value?

Comment: diagonally as the arrows show.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is to help me with the code how to read the array as the arrows show at the image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that along each diagonal, the **difference*** `i - j` is constant. So you have a nested double loop, where the outer one goes over the difference:

- First round: Difference -14, `arr[0][14]`
- Second round: Difference -13, `arr[0][13]`, `arr[1][14]`
- ...
- last round: Difference +9, `arr[9][0]`.

In code:

```
for (int d = -14; d < 10; ++d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d + 15 && i < 10; ++i)
    {
      if (i < d) continue;

      // access arr[i][i - d];
      printf("[%d, %d]\n", i, i - d);
    }
}
```

Note the appearance of the numbers `10` and `15` in the code; the picture is readily generalized to arbitrary array bounds.

*) Or, as @Alexey points out, the **sum** `i + j` is constant, depending on where the origin is in your picture; in that case, modify the loop as follows:

```
for (int d = 0; d <= 9 + 14; ++d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= d && i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if (i + 15 <= d) continue;
        // use arr[i][d - i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would upvote for the idea, but: the result is [0, 14] [0, 13] [1, 14] [0, 12] [1, 13] [2, 14] etc while it should (I think) be [0,0] [1,0] [0,1] [2,0] [1,1] [0,2] etc.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: That's not what the question asks. You are describing antidiagonals, but the picture clearly asks for diagonals. Either way, the modification is trivial.

Comment: Instead of i = 0 and check if its < d each iteration, you can do "for (int i = d > 0 ? d : 0; ..." (of course, you can compute the starting i before the loop, to make the code more legible, but I think you got the point).

Comment: @fbafelipe: I don't think your code is correct, but in any event I'd probably just leave the hoisting to the compiler, which should spot this and optimize accordingly; as it stands the loop condition is fairly readable. You can of course stick a manual `min(d + 15, 10)` in there if you like, why not.

Comment: Well, the directions in which array indices increase are not specified in the question, so at least two different interpretations are possible. You took the direction as for Euclidean coordinates, and I took the one that is typically used for matrices. Perhaps it's just subjective interpretation; +1 then :)

Comment: Your solution's really clever but quite hard to understand ;)

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: Haha, you're right - I had simply put the (0,0) in the bottom-left automatically, but of course it could be anywhere else! OK, let the OP clarify if she wants.

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you help me expand this algorith to work for this picture also from left to right?
Thank you in advance...
[link](http://tinypic.com/r/264ga2w/5)

Comment: @Buxme: For going along rows (or columns) first, you'll need the remainder operation (`%`). (But that won't work if your rows and columns are infinitely long, while the diagonal method does work in that case :-).)

Comment: @KerrekSB I can't understand what do you mean. Sorry for that. I'm a newbie in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i, j;

// left arrows
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(j = 0; j <= i && j < columns; j++)
        doSomethingWithCell(grid[i][j]);

// bottom arrows
for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    for(int j = rows - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        doSomethingWithCell(grid[j][i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 bits:

```
void scan_array(int* data, int height, int width, void (*handler)(int)) {
    int startY = 0;
    for (; startY < height; startY ++) {
    int ypos = startY;
    int xpos = 0;
    while (ypos >= 0 && xpos < width) {
        handler(*(data + ypos * width + xpos));
        ypos--;
        xpos++;
    }
    }

    int startX = 1;
    for (; startX < width; startX ++) {
    int xpos = startX;
    int ypos = height - 1;
    while (ypos >= 0 && xpos < width) {
        handler(*(data + ypos * width + xpos));
        ypos--;
        xpos++;
    }
    }
}

void print_elem(int elem) {
    printf("%d ", elem);
}

int main(void) {
    int data[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {10, 20, 30} };
    scan_array(&data[0][0], 2, 3, print_elem);
    printf("\n========\n");

    int data2[3][2] = { {1, 2},  {10, 20}, {100, 200} };
    scan_array(&data2[0][0], 3, 2, print_elem);
    printf("\n========\n");

    int square[2][2] = { {1, 2},  {10, 20}};
    scan_array(&square[0][0], 2, 2, print_elem);
    printf("\n========\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are labeling it with the upper left most cell as 0,0 and the lower right most cell as 10,15. And doSomething is whatever you are doing in this scanning.

```
//First all the ones starting in col=0
for (rowStart=0; rowStart<numRows ; rowStart++){
    colStart=0; //Start on the left boundary
    rowOffset=colOffset=0;
    while (rowStart+rowOffset > 0 && colStart+colOffset<numCols){
      doSomething(array[rowStart+rowOffset][colStart+colOffset]);
      colOffset++; rowOffset--; // Move one space to the right and one space up
    }
//Second all the diagonals starting in the maxRow
for (colStart=0; colStart<numCols ; numCol++){
    rowStart=numRows-1; //Start at the bottom
    rowOffset=colOffset=0;
    while (rowStart+rowOffset > 0 && colStart+colOffset<numCols){
      doSomething(array[rowStart+rowOffset][colStart+colOffset]);
      colOffset++; rowOffset--; // Move one space to the right and one space up
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scan every 14 elements instead of 15.  This way you get the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming I understand your question, which I read as:
I want to draw a diagonal line through an array and visit each cell that the line crosses.

Use the [Bresenham Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to find out which cells to visit in your array and then return an array composed of the cells that Bresenham found for you.  If you read the wikipedia article I linked, you'll see functions called plot and setPixel.  The input to those functions are the cells you should be reading from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLS = 15;

    int array[ROWS][COLS];

    int i, j;

    // left arrows
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i && j < COLS; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &array[i - j][j]);
        }
    }

    // bottom arrows
    for (j = 1; j < COLS; ++j) {
        for (i = 0; i < ROWS && j + i < COLS; ++i) {
            scanf("%d", &array[ROWS - i - 1][j + i]);
        }
    }

    // dump to a file, just for testing
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; ++j) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        fputc('\n', fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```